# In the Rayleigh–Jeans Law, why polarization is two?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

When we count mode of wave in  cavity radiator, why the "2" is multiplied by polarization?
Polarization has two base, but the number of polarization state maybe infinity and continues.
Linear polarization, Circularly polarization, Elliptically polarization,...
It is countless.
Why the two is multiplied?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I'm afraid that your post is a little unclear.  Can you edit your post to try to explain what you mean by "the number of polarization state maybe infinity and continues"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarized light on a plane is a superposition of independent components $E_x$ and $E_y$. Considering circular polarization, there are again two independent components, since two distinct rotations are conceivable.

On the whole, we pay attention to the **number of independent polarization states** -which is 2- while counting independent modes, thus $N(v)dv=\frac{4*π*\rho^{2}d\rho}{8}$ is multiplied by 2.

Comment: I has just understood!